# Python Pass Execution to External Process

Tags: python, python-3.x

I would like to do some computation in Python and then pass or transfer to an interactive process, such as `ssh`. I want to dive into the new process. This would (preferably) be something where Python hands the interaction over and quits, but alternatively could be something the user interacts with and then returns to the original Python process when done.

I have tried this with `subprocess.run()`, but don't get to do anything on the remote host and the Python process continues after `subprocess.run` times out.

```python
myCommand = ['ssh','hostname']
subprocess.run(myCommand, useShell = False)
```

Is this something Python can handle or am I using the wrong tool?

Comment: Probably you want something from the `os.execv` family of functions, although take care to read the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.execl

Comment: What precisely are you passing/transferring? It's a little unclear if you just want the launch a plain `ssh` session that the user interacts with directly, vs. launching things remotely via `ssh`. If the latter, typically you want to use a library like `paramiko` that gives you in-process control of the `ssh` session, rather than trying to kludge it via communicating with a subprocess using piped text.

Comment: I am generating the hostname programmatically and then ssh-ing into that hostname. I want to ssh to the host like I typed it in from the command line but I need Python to generate the hostname. I suppose I could have Python generate the text `ssh mYh0rr1bleHO5t` and then copy paste. I am hoping Python can launch the ssh process without my interaction.